# Principal axes of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I try to find the definition of the main axes of a matrix. I saw this phrase in some exercise:

> Let $A$ be a positive matrix, $f:G\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function, $G$ an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I need to find the orthogonal coordinate transformation $y=Px$ such that the main axis on $y$'s coordinates will be the principle axis of $A$.

The book says to diagonalize $A$: $PAP^t=D$ and to choose $P$ to be the transformation.

What is the definition of principal axes of matrix?

Comment: the principal axis of a matrix $A$ are the basis vectors so that $A$ has a diagonal matrix representation.

Comment: I'm troubled by the "the" in this statement. Is this an English translation issue? Do we mean *a* principal [NOT principle] axis?

Comment: I suppose it could be a confounding of *principal axes* (geometry) and *principle component* (from statistics --- the principal axis associated to the dominant eigenvalue, although usually used the the phrase "principal component analysis", where we look for the top few eigenvalues). Either way, the SVD is probably the way to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Often, principal axes of a matrix refer to its eigenvectors. With this diagonalization, $P$ is the matrix of eigenvectors.

Comment: when you diagnolize matrix with orthogonal matrix p,p doesn't have to contain eigenvectors(grahm schmidt process might change them)

Comment: actually, you can only diagonalize $A$ using orthogonal matrix $P$ when $A$ is symmetric (why?). It follows that $P$ is *always* composed of eigenvector columns.

Answer (score 0):

This answer contains:

- The origin and meaning of the term *principal axes*.
- The relationship between principal axes and eigenvectors.
- An example of principal axes determination.

---

**Notion of principal axes**

> What is the definition of principal axes of matrix?

Principal axes is a term initially used for [quadratic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function), i.e. functions of the form $ax^{2}+bxy+cy^{2} = \text {constant}$. The curves are also called [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section), they include ellipses, parabolas and hyperbolas. A conic section has axes of symmetry, e.g. for an ellipse, major and minor axes.

[image]

For a parabola, the symmetry axis is [the line dividing the curve into two halves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola), for an hyperbola, there are two symmetry axes, [the transverse and conjugate axes](https://learn.saylor.org/mod/book/tool/print/index.php?id=54173&chapterid=39405).

But regardless of the curve, the symmetry axes of a quadratic function are called the *principal axes of the function*.

**Principal axes and eigenvectors**

The link with eigenvectors results from the fact a quadratic function can be written in matrix form:

$
ax_{1}^{2}+bx_{1}x_{2}+cx_{2}^{2}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} & x_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
A
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$
with $
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b/2\\
b/2 & c
\end{bmatrix}
$

As matrix A is symmetric, it can be diagonalized using eigenvalues and eigenvectors, it exists $P$ and $D$ such that:

$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b/2\\
b/2 & c
\end{bmatrix}
=
PDP^{-1}
$

The principal axes (the axes of symmetry of the curve) are the eigenvectors, the column vectors in $P$, and because $A$ is symmetric, the eigenvectors are orthogonal.

(The orthogonal columns in $P$ can be normalized to get an orthogonal matrix.)

**Equation of the curve in the basis of the eigenvectors**

One nice thing is we change the standard basis by the orthogonal basis defined by the eigenvectors:

Let
$
x
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$
be the coordinates in the standard basis and let
$
y
=
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$
be the coordinates in the eigenvectors basis. Then $x=Py$ and we can rewrite the quadratic equation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
ax_{1}^{2}+bx_{1}x_{2}+cx_{2}^{2}
&
= x^{T}Ax
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}
&
x_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
A
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}
\end{bmatrix} \\
& = (Py)^{T}A(Py) \\
& = y^{T}(P^{T}AP)y \\
& = y^{T}Dy \\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1} &
y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
D
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

(See also [principal axes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem)). As $D$ is a diagonal matrix there will be only terms in $y_1$ and $y_{2}$, no more cross-terms like $x_{1}x_{2}$.

The principles can be generalized to any number of variables in the equation, not only 2 as here.

**Example**

Example borrowed from [Peter A. Brown](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Eking/coursedir/m308a01/Projects/m308a01-pdf/brown.pdf). Ellipse defined by $5x_{1}^{2} - 4x_{1}x_{2} + 5x_{2}^{2} = 1$.

- What are the principal axes?
- How can we express the ellipse in the basis of the principal axes?

Eigenvectors of the associated matrix:

- The associated matrix is
  $
  A = \begin{bmatrix}
  5 & -2\\
  -2 & 5
  \end{bmatrix}
  $
- Solving $\det(\lambda I-A) = 0$, we get the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1}=3$ and $\lambda_{2}=7$.
- Substituting eigenvalues in $(\lambda I-A)X=0$, we get the eigenvectors
  $
  X_{1} =
  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
  $
  and
  $
  X_{2} =
  \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
  $
- The eigenvectors can be normalized by dividing by their magnitude $\sqrt 2$:
  $
  X_{1} =
  \begin{bmatrix} 
  1 / \sqrt 2 \\ 
  1 / \sqrt 2
  \end{bmatrix}
  $
  and
  $
  X_{2} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  -1 / \sqrt 2 \\
  1 / \sqrt 2
  \end{bmatrix}
  $

  The eignevectors are the principal axes of the ellipse.

Diagonalized form of the associated matrix:

- The diagonal matrix is made of eigenvalues:
  $
  D =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  3 & 0\\
  0 & 7
  \end{bmatrix}
  $
- $P$ is made of eigenvectors:
  $P =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 / \sqrt 2 & -1 / \sqrt 2 \\
  1 / \sqrt 2 & 1 / \sqrt 2
  \end{bmatrix}
  $

  P is the matrix of a rotation by 45°, thus the ellipse is angled at 45°.
- As P is orthogonal, its inverse is simply its transpose:
  $
  P^{-1} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 / \sqrt 2 & 1 / \sqrt 2 \\
  -1 / \sqrt 2 & 1 / \sqrt 2
  \end{bmatrix}
  $
- Diagonalized form of $A$:
  $\begin {aligned}
  A
  &
  = PDP^{-1}
  \\
  \begin{bmatrix}
  5 & -2\\
  -2 & 5
  \end{bmatrix}
  & =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 / \sqrt 2 & -1 / \sqrt 2 \\
  1 / \sqrt 2 & 1 / \sqrt 2
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  3 & 0\\
  0 & 7
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 / \sqrt 2 & 1 / \sqrt 2 \\
  -1 / \sqrt 2 & 1 / \sqrt 2
  \end{bmatrix}
  \end {aligned}
  $

We can re-express the function using principal axes coordinates:

- Using $D$:

  $
  \begin {aligned}
  5x_{1}^{2} - 4x_{1}x_{2} + 5x_{2}^{2}
  & =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  y_{1} & y_{2}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  3 & 0\\
  0 & 7
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  y_{1}\\
  y_{2}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \\
  & =
  3y_{1}^{2} + 7y_{2}^{2}
  \end {aligned}
  $

This ellipse is the one plotted at the top of this answer. It is indeed angled at 45°.